# PHP sending form accorded to a url token

Tags: php, database

i'm learning php since a week from now, and one of my project is to make a form that adapt fields about a url token.

For example: if the user is a student token will be **index.php?token=e3**
the user is a professionnal will be **index.php?token=p4**

i'm realy happy because everything is working, except the last part.. the **POST of the user informations** in my db called "test" which as a single table called form and i the db got good settings, the table is well designed with int-varchars, anything that can handle the datas.

i would like to atleast make it work for e3 then i'll be able to adapt for the others, that's why i give you an example of what i did since now, maybe i'm missing something important but i got no php errors, the datas are not sending when i press **send** button and the page refresh as index.php

if you guys got an idea, you don't need to tell me realy how to do, i just need someone better than me that could tell me "well you should look at sessions" or something else that is wrong because i have no clue to debug i'm stuck since yesterday on this problem.

Here is my code remember if you want to make it appear clearly you need to specify the token "?token=e3"
thank you in advance everyone who'll help me:

```
<?php
 
session_start();

$connectionSql = array(
                        "hote" => "localhost",
                        "base" => "test",
                        "user" => "root",
                        "pwd" => "",
                        );
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $connectionSql["hote"] . ";dbname=" . $connectionSql["base"], 
                    $connectionSql["user"], $connectionSql["pwd"]);
    /*var_dump($db);*/
    $db->exec("set names utf8");
} catch  (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$getWholeUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."";
$url = substr($getWholeUrl , -2);

if ($url=="e3" && isset($_POST['send'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['gender']) AND !empty($_POST['name']) AND 
        !empty($_POST['firstname']) AND !empty($_POST['mail']) AND 
        !empty($_POST['phone']) AND !empty($_POST['speciality']) AND 
        $_POST['speciality'] != "Votre spécialité" AND !empty($_POST['year']) AND 
        !empty($_POST['birthday']) AND !empty($_POST['school']) AND 
        !empty($_POST['zipcode']) AND !empty($_FILES['attachment']) AND 
        !empty($_FILES['pi'])) 
    {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
        $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']);
        $mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $speciality = $_POST['speciality'];
        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
        $school = htmlspecialchars($_POST['school']);
        $zipcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST['zipcode']);
        $filename = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
        $idname = $_FILES['pi']['name'];

        $reqmail= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE mail = ?");
        $reqmail->execute(array($mail));
        $mailexist = $reqmail->rowCount();
        if($mailexist == 0) {
            if (filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_mail)) {
                if (is_numeric($phone) == true && preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $phone)) {
                    if (is_numeric($year) == true) {
                        if(!empty($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['pi']['name'])){

                            if ($_FILES['attachment']['error'] == 0 && $_FILES['attachment']['size'] < 2097152 && $_FILES['pi']['error'] == 0 && $_FILES['pi']['size'] < 2097152) {

                                $extension = pathinfo($filename);
                                if ($extension["extension"] == "jpg" || $extension["extension"] == "png" || $extension["extension"] == "pdf") {
                                    $extensionid = pathinfo($idname);
                                    if($extensionid["extension"] == 'jpg' || $extensionid['extension'] == "png" || $extensionid['extension'] == "pdf") {

                                        $req = $db->query('SELECT MAX(id) FROM form');

                                        $res = $req->fetchColumn();

                                        $res += 1;

                                        if(!is_dir('img/')) {
                                            mkdir('img/', 0755);
                                        }

                                        if(!is_dir('img/img' . $res . '/')){
                                            mkdir('img/img' . $res . '/', 0755);
                                        }

                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], 'img/img' . $res . '/' . $res . $filename);
                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pi']['tmp_name'], 'img/img' . $res . '/' . $res . 'id' . $idname);

                                        $require = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `form` (`gender`, `name`, `firstname`, `mail`, `phone`, `speciality`, `year`, `birthday`, `school`, `zipcode`, `attachment`, `idcard`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

                                        $require->execute(array($gender, $name, $firstname, $mail, $phone, $speciality, $year, $birthday, $school, $zipcode, $res . $filename, $res . $idname));
                                        $succes = "Form as been sent !";
                                    }else{
                                        $erreur = "idcard's extension isn't admitted.";
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    $erreur = "attachment's extension isn't admitted.";
                                }
                            }else{
                                $erreur = "File too big - Max 2Mo";
                            }
                        }else{
                            $erreur = "Please join the two required attached files.";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $erreur = $year . " isn't a valable year !";
                    }
                } else {
                    $erreur = $phone . " isn't a right phone number !";
                }
            }else{
                $erreur = "invalid mail";
            }
        }else{
            $erreur = "mail already exists !";
        }
    }else{
        $erreur = "please complete all the fields !";
    }
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/icon-x" href="images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div align="center">
            <h1 class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
            </h1>
            <?php
            if(isset($succes))
            {
                echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">".$succes."</div>";
            }
            if(isset($erreur))
            {
                echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">".$erreur."</div>";
            }
            ?>

            <div class="image">
                <section>
                    <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="radioclass">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="1"/>
                            <label class="btn" for="gender">Woman</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="2"/>
                            <label class="btn" for="gender">Man</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="3"/>
                            <label class="btn" for="gender">Unicorn</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="user-input-wrp">
                            <div class="user-input-name">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/ required>
                                <span class="name">name</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-input-surname">
                                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/ required>
                                <span class="firstname">firstname</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-input-mail">
                                <input type="mail" name="mail" id="mail"/ required>
                                <span class="mail">mail</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-input-mobile">
                                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required>
                                <span class="phone">phone</span>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                                $getWholeUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."";
                                if(substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='e3'){ 
                                $listespeciality = array("your speciality",
                                                "Fitness",
                                                "Bodybuilding",
                                                "Flower-eating");              
                                echo "<select name=\"speciality\" id=\"speciality\">";
                                foreach ($listespeciality as $indice => $speciality) {
                                    echo "<option value=\"";
                                    echo $speciality;
                                    echo "\">";
                                    echo $speciality;
                                    echo "</option>";
                                }
                                echo "</select>";
                            } 
                            else {
                                echo "<div class=\"user-input-seccia\">"."<input type=\"text\" name=\"secteur\" id=\"secteur\">"."<span class=\"secteur\">activity</span>"."</div>";
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="user-input-year">
                                <input type="text" name="year" id="year" required>
                                <span class="year">Year of activity</span>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            $getWholeUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."";
                            if(substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='e3'){ 
                                echo "
                            <div class=\"user-input-building\">
                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"school\" id=\"school\" required>
                                <span class=\"school\">school</span>
                            </div>";}
                            else if(substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='p4' || substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='o1') {
                                echo "
                                <div class=\"user-input-siret\">
                                    <input maxlength=\"14\" type=\"text\" name=\"idcode\" id=\"idcode\" required>
                                    <span class=\"siret\">identity code</span>
                                </div>";} ?>
                            
                            <?php
                                $getWholeUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."";
                                if(substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='a2') {
                                $listmedia = array("Blog",
                                "Facebook",
                                "Instagram",
                                "Own website");              
                                 echo "<select name=\"media\" id=\"media\">";
                                         foreach ($listmedia as $indice => $media) {
                                             echo "<option value=\"";
                                             echo $media;
                                            echo "\">";
                                            echo $media;
                                            echo "</option>";
                                         }
                                            echo "</select>";
                                         } ?>
                                         
                            <?php $getWholeUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."";
                            if(substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='o1' || substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='p4'){ 
                                echo "
                            <div class=\"user-input-company\">
                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"company\" id=\"company\" required/>
                                <span class=\"company\">company</span>
                            </div>";}
                            else if (substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='a2') {
                                echo "
                            <div class=\"user-input-url\">
                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"url\" id=\"url\" required/>
                                <span class=\"url\">Link of media</span>
                            </div>";}
                            else if (substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='e3'){
                                echo "
                            <div class=\"user-input-zipcode\">
                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"zipcode\" id=\"zipcode\" required/>
                                <span class=\"zipcode\">Zipcode</span>
                            </div>"
                            ;}?>
                            <?php if (substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='e3' || substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='a2' || substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='p4'){
                                echo "
                            <input type=\"Date\" name=\"birthday\" id=\"birthday\" min=\"1930-01-01\" max=\"2020-12-29\" value=\"2000-01-01\">
                            <span class=\"birthday\">birthday</span>
                            ";}
                            else echo "<br><br><br><br><br>"
                            ?>
                            <?php if (substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='e3') {
                            echo "
                            <div class=\"user-input-attachment\">
                                    <div>"; if(isset($error)) echo $error; echo "</p></div>
                                    <input type=\"file\" name=\"attachment\" id=\"attachment\" value=\"\"/>
                                    <span class=\"attachment\">attachment:</span>
                            </div>"; }
                            else if (substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='p4' || substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='a2') { echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br>";}
                            else if (substr($getWholeUrl , -2)=='o1') { echo "<br><br><br><br><br>";}
                            ?>
                            <div class="user-input-idcard">
                                    <div><p><?php if(isset($error)) echo $error;?></p></div>
                                    <input type="file" name="pi" id="pi" value=""/>
                                    <span class="idcard">identity card :</span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Send"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you look at the [`$_GET` array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and probably also the [`$_POST` Array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: I also suggest you look at making your `id` column an [Auto Increment column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) and save yourself a whole lot of heart ache

Comment: Don't try to run before you can walk. You've got a whole bunch of form fields, file uploads, multiple SQL queries, a bunch of validation ... Break the problem down, and write some much smaller test scripts to get the hang of things: submit a form and display its result back on the page, run an SQL SELECT query and display that on the page, one by one. Once you know how to do the individual parts, you can start putting them together - or, if you get stuck on one part, you can ask a much more focussed question here.

Comment: thank you guys for your comments :), i'm gonna try step by steps then and yes id is in auto increment in my table